# bake settings logged command different from the actual command

Tags: python

When changing the bake settings i.e, enable/remove diffuse. The log in the info panel is different from the actual command. Is it a bug or am I missing something ?[image]

Comment: Yep you've found a minor bug.  These should be reported to the  [official bug tracker](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/2217).